# How to update only orthogonal (but not displayed) data of the cell in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

We can use [cell().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()) to set cell data. But what if we need to just update [orthogonal](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) cell properties, but not main `display` data, which is rendered in the cell? I.e. we have this data for the cell and we just want to update `current_value` while keeping `display` unchanged in the DOM:

```
"digit": {
    "display": "<select><option selected value=`1`>1</option><option value=`2`>2</option></select>",
    "current_value": "1"
}
```

My use case is using `<select>` within a cell — when option changes I want to keep select in place and only change orthogonal data.

Comment: Could you perhaps illustrate what you mean using a JSFiddle? Having a better idea of what you want to accomplish might help us help you.

Comment: @annoyingmouse will do

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) API method to get/set the data for the selected row.

For example, to increment `current_value` when a row is clicked on:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table.row( this ).data();

    data.digit.current_value++;

    table
        .row( this )
        .data( data )
        .draw(false);
} );
```

Comment: Seems like there is a misunderstanding. Example data in my question is a data for single cell (not row), with [orthogonal](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) property ```current_value``` and ```display``` property which is what rendered within a cell. I want to update only ```current_value``` data property of that single cell, while keeping ```display``` unchanged. And that is what causing a problem cause ```cell().data()``` seems to rewrite whole data for the cell causing cell rerender which is what I want to avoid. Maybe jsfiddle will explain this better

Comment: @Andrey, the code in my example does exactly that, it updates `current_value` without touching any other fields. Click event handler is just to illustrate the idea. If you could provide a simple jsFiddle, that would be a help. You can use [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ep2f95za/) for a start.

Comment: yep, sorry, my bad, it indeed updates the data. But to actually make use of this updated data (in my case for sorting) datatable cache needs to be updated to take new data into account. [cell().invalidate()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().invalidate()) does that but again — it redrawing the cell with its ```display``` property which I was trying to avoid whole the time... So any method to "update" cell data causing its contents to rerender

Comment: and ```table.row( this ).data( data ).draw(false);``` also rerendering cell ```display```-content...

Comment: @Andrey, I think I understand what you mean, the `draw()` call resets the `select` element and according to the documentation `row().data()` does not update the table's internal caches of data until the `draw()` method is called.

Comment: Moreover ```row().data()``` makes effect like ```cell().data()``` — it resets the DOM of the cells using ```display``` data property of each cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117834/discussion-between-gyrocode-com-and-andrey).